# How to iterate over request parameters

Tags: go, buffalo

I'd like to iterate over the request parameters in the request handler.
I'm following the example from the [documentation](https://gobuffalo.io/fr/docs/context#ranging-over-parameters), but I can't get it to work.

By following the getting started guide and using the piece of code provided to range over parameters, I get :

```
actions/home.go:8:26: undefined: url
```

Is there a way to iterate over the request parameters using buffalo's context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the url package [link](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values)

`import "net/url"`